# Microsoft Graph v2.0 admin consent errors asking for v2.0

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I get this response when using the `/adminconsent` endpoint in step 3 from [this documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/auth_v2_service.md). I have registered the application with the [v2.0 endpoint](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), so I am not sure why it thinks this is v1.0. Also, the account I am using to login is a work account (not microsoft account like the error indicates).

```
{ 
  error: 'access_denied',
  error_description: 'AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this api version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.\r\nTrace ID: 11eec023-c150-42f2-a9e6-13b52db30b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 00b57bc3-9e86-47c2-907b-579357344266\r\nTimestamp: 2018-01-10 19:26:00Z',
  admin_consent: 'True',
  tenant: *Redacted*,
  state: *Redacted* 
}
```

This is how I form the `/adminconsent` endpoint. It seems like I must be doing something obvious?

```
const msUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=${clientId}&state=${state}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(callbackUrl)}`;
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the `client id` that you're passing is the one from apps.dev.microsoft.com?

Comment: Also make sure that if you've used an AD account to register the app that you did so under "Converged applications" and not under "Azure AD only applications". Converged == v2

Comment: It is the client id from apps.dev.microsoft.com - I will verify the converged applications portion thank you for the suggestion. Edit: Where do I see that actually? I created a new application and did not see that option anywhere.

Comment: Can you try using the Tenant Id or Tenant Name instead of *common*?